# How do I properly implement a Realm List into my custom object?

Tags: java, android, realm

So I'm trying to implement a Realm List into my class, however, the documentation that I can find at [Realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships) doesn't clarify whether it needs a getter/setter and if it does what it should look like.  So here's my code:

```
public class Novel extends RealmObject {

   @PrimaryKey
   private static int id;

   @Required
   private static String name;

   //Establish relationship with Novel (single) and Chapter (many)
   private RealmList<Chapter> chapters;

   public static int getId() {
       return id;
   }//end getId

   public static void setId(int id) {
       Novel.id = id;
   }//end setId

   public static String getName() {
    return name;
   }//end getName

   public static void setName(String name) {
    Novel.name = name;
   }//end setName

}//end Novel.class
```

In order to store an object in a Realm Database, all variables have to have getters/setters. However, since I am using a `RealmList`, how do I structure my getter/setter correctly?

Here's the code Android Studio gives me, but it just doesn't look right.

```
public RealmList<Chapter> getChapters() {
    return chapters;
}

public void setChapters(RealmList<Chapter> chapters) {
    this.chapters = chapters;
}
```

The getter looks ok, however, the setter makes no sense to me in how it would work with the `RealmList` correctly.

**tldr**: What should my getter/setter be in order to properly implement the `RealmList` in my custom object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RealmList` implements all useful interfaces:

```
java.lang.Iterable<E>, java.util.Collection<E>, java.util.List<E>
```

If you want to add new `Chapter` to the `Novel` use code similar to:

```
Chapter chapter = realm.copyToRealm(new Chapter());
novel.getChapters().add(chapter);
```

If you want to replace all chapters with new one:

```
RealmList<Chapter> chapters = new RealmList<Chapter>();
chapters.add(new Chapter());
chapters.add(new Chapter());
chapters.add(new Chapter());
chapters.add(new Chapter());

chapters = realm.copyToRealm(chapters);
novel.setChapters(chapters);
```

Comment: I understand that stuff however this does not answer my question.  I'm not sure what my getter/setter has to be for the RealmList in my Custom Object file (in this case Novel.java).

Comment: your setters/getters are ok in your question. RealObject(and RealmList) is just proxy object. This means that you can access/modify fields only using it and they should be declared in such way.

Comment: Ok that's what I needed to verify.  Thanks for you help!